# What does alter ego mean?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of alter ego? Why are only these two words 'alter' and 'ego' used specifically?

Comment: For context, I suspect the OP is trying to get clarification to the answers to his/her question here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/51286

Comment: Yeah..i came across the word for the first time and it made me curious!! Plus here the people explain their answer to the tiny detail and its convincing than google i feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It's one word, *alterego*</strike>.  In philosophy, *ego* can [mean](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20alterego#q=define%20ego) 
"(in metaphysics) a conscious thinking subject."  *Alter* here means something other than the main thing.  So *alterego* means your consciousness that is not your main consciousness, as you present it to the world.

Comment: CDO says it's an open compound, alter ego, as OP says. Where have you found support for your claim that it is  a single orthographic word?

Comment: I have never seen it written as a single word, only as a fixed two-word expression.

Comment: My mistake!  Sorry!

Comment: _Alter ego_ was recorded in English in 1537 (according to the OED) in the sense " A person regarded and treated as another version of oneself; an intimate and trusted friend", long before _ego_ was used in philosophy (1827).

Answer (score 2):

It's Latin for "other self." In other words, another identity (secret or otherwise).

Comment: Hello, Mike. ELU expects answers (and where possible questions) to be supported by references from accepted works (dictionaries, Wikipedia etc). In fact, this question will probably be closed because it would have been so easy for OP themself to have Googled what you have written.